# Lipschitzise a function preserving order

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are real valued continuous and strictly increasing functions defined on $[0,\infty)$ with value zero at zero. Furthermore, suppose that $f<g<h$ on all their domain, that $f$ and $h$ are locally Lipschitz at zero and that $g$ is continuously differentiable except in zero.

Can we claim that there exists a function $\hat{g}$ with the same properties as $g$ but locally Lipschitz at zero?

Comment: By locally lipschitz at zero do you mean $|f(x)|/x \le M$ when $x$ is small?

Comment: How about $\hat g=(f+h)/2$?

Comment: What do you mean by the same properties as $g$?

Comment: I forgot to add that g is C1 on $(0,\infty)$. Locally Lipschitz at a point means that there is a neighborhood around the point where the function is Lipschitz.